# Creating a Result type with Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, error-handling, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Closure Compiler and I'd like to have a Rust-like `Result` type which either contains a value of a certain type, or contains no value and an error, to represent the return value from a function.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
/**
 * @param {function(Result<Element>)} callback
*/
function bar (callback) {        
    if (...) {
        var elem = ...;
        callback(Result.ok(elem));
    } else {
        callback(Result.err(new Error("...")));
    }
}

bar(function (result) {
    if (result.ok) {
        // guaranteed to be a non-error result here - no warning
        console.log(result.val.nodeType);
    } else {
        // closure should produce a warning here about undefined prop
        console.log(result.val.nodeType);
    }
});
```

Possible implementation (doesn't throw warnings though):

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @template T
 * @param {boolean} ok
 * @param {T} val
 * @param {Error} err
**/
function Result (ok, val, err) {
    this.ok = ok;
    this.val = val;
    this.err = err;
}

/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T=} val
 * @return {OkResult<T>}
**/
Result.ok = function (val) {
    return new OkResult(val);
};

/**
 * @param {Error} err
 * @param {Error=} previous
 * @return {ErrResult}
**/
Result.err = function (err, previous) {
    err['previous'] = previous;
    return new ErrResult(err);
};

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Result}
 * @template T
 * @param {T} val
**/
function OkResult (val) {
    this.ok = true;  
    this.val = val;
    this.err = null;
}

/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {Result}
 * @param {Error} err
**/
function ErrResult (err) {
    this.ok = false;
    this.val = null;
    this.err = err;
}
```

I've tried to implement this with a `Result` superclass and two `OkResult` and `ErrResult` subclasses, but when I try to write code that should produce a warning, I don't get any.

Is there some way of creating a `Result` type that has the attributes specified above? One that will safely warn when trying to access an error result as though it was an ok result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using classical inheritance is definitely the way to do this. Instead of testing for an `obj.ok` property, the check should be `instanceof`.

```
bar(function (result) {
  if (result instanceof OkResult) {
    // instanceof tests are recognized by the compiler
    // and automatically tightens the types.
    console.log(result.val.nodeType);
  } else if (result instanceof ErrorResult) {
    // closure produces a warning here about undefined prop
    console.log(result.val.nodeType);
  }
});
```

Also, the compiler only warns about missing properties when the property cannot exist. In order for that to be true, the property must not be defined on any parent class.

[See a working example](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bfunction%28Result%253CElement%253E%29%257D%2520callback%250A*%252F%250Afunction%2520bar%2520%28callback%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520%28window%255B'isTrue'%255D%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520elem%2520%253D%2520document.createElement%28'div'%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520callback%28new%2520OkResult%28elem%29%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%2520else%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520callback%28new%2520ErrorResult%28new%2520Error%28%2522...%2522%29%29%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D%250A%250Abar%28function%2520%28result%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520%28result%2520instanceof%2520OkResult%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520guaranteed%2520to%2520be%2520a%2520non-error%2520result%2520here%2520-%2520no%2520warning%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log%28result.val.nodeType%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%2520else%2520if%2520%28result%2520instanceof%2520ErrorResult%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520closure%2520should%2520produce%2520a%2520warning%2520here%2520about%2520undefined%2520prop%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log%28result.val.nodeType%29%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D%29%253B%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540constructor%250A%2520**%252F%250Afunction%2520Result%2520%28%29%2520%257B%257D%250A%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540constructor%250A%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BResult%253CT%253E%257D%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257BT%257D%2520val%250A%2520*%2520%2540template%2520T%250A%2520**%252F%250Afunction%2520OkResult%2520%28val%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.val%2520%253D%2520val%253B%250A%257D%250AOkResult.prototype%2520%253D%2520Object.create%28Result.prototype%29%253B%250A%250A%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540constructor%250A%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BResult%257D%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257BError%257D%2520err%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257BError%253D%257D%2520previous%250A%2520**%252F%250Afunction%2520ErrorResult%2520%28err%252C%2520previous%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.err%2520%253D%2520err%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520%28previous%29%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520this.err%255B'previous'%255D%2520%253D%2520previous%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D%250AErrorResult.prototype%2520%253D%2520Object.create%28Result.prototype%29%253B)

Comment: Thanks, Chad! Also, I took the `if (result instanceof ErrorResult)` away and changed the body to `console.log(result.err)` and it still compiled, but doing `result.blah` gave a warning (as I'd hope). Does that mean it's actually determining that the only two types of `Result` it could be are `OkResult` and `ErrorResult` and doing a process of elimination to determine that it is an `ErrorResult`? If so, wow, that's awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It means it could be either type.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. It would've been surprising if Closure had advanced to that level of analysis. Thanks for the help.